# display data in database using check box

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, arraylist

I have database where table name **user_access** where in my **Column table**

name **Rule** inside column Rule have value '1101'

the problem is I want to display in **Check Box Edit Form**

as value in my **Column Rule** example ilustration :

```
| Rule |
| =====|
| 1101 |
```

I want to display in my check box like this where (* its mean check)

```
[*] Setting
[*] Change Password
[ ] Delete
[*] Add User
```

Can anyone show me the logic code using codeignitier?

Comment: not getting what you want, if value is 1101 then it should be [*]?

Comment: its mean 1 is checkbox and 0 not checkbox

Comment: Your homework...?

Comment: Hi Groenhen, can u help me to display in view? what is code in module im confuse between using substring and xplode

Comment: @WahyuArtadianto explode the value and then check.

Comment: Hi Pathik Vejani, help i need a code